# Insert a newline character every 64 characters using Python

Tags: regex, python

Using Python I need to insert a newline character into a string every 64 characters. In Perl it's easy:

```
s/(.{64})/$1\n/
```

How could this be done using regular expressions in Python?
Is there a more pythonic way to do it?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Same as in Perl, but with a backslash instead of the dollar for accessing groups:

```
s = "0123456789"*100 # test string
import re
print re.sub("(.{64})", "\\1\n", s, 0, re.DOTALL)
```

[`re.DOTALL`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) is the equivalent to Perl's `s/` option.

Comment: QUERY: If the source string is ``s2="0123456789"*200`` , your solution seems to be broken, who **only** inserts exactly 16 '\n' (on Python 2.7.1). Any fix?

Comment: Nice find. The problem was that there is another parameter "count" between the search string and the flags (`re.DOTALL`). Since I forgot that parameter, re.DOTALL (value 16) was used as maximum number of replacements.

Comment: @AndiDog: is there a way to use a variable instead of `64`?

Comment: Well, just insert your number instead of 64 ?!

Comment: how would you achieve this for a multiline input and convert for eg. a line `thisisafile` to `thi,sisafi,l,e` (take the number of character after which to enter a character to be hardcoded)like in this eg it would have been `3 6 1 1`

Comment: I think @Forethinker meant "use a variable", not "use a different constant". `"(.{%d})"%varname` seems a bit hackish; there must be a better way.

Answer (score 37):

without regexp:

```py
def insert_newlines(string, every=64):
    lines = []
    for i in range(0, len(string), every):
        lines.append(string[i:i+every])
    return '\n'.join(lines)
```

shorter but less readable (imo):

```py
def insert_newlines(string, every=64):
    return '\n'.join(string[i:i+every] for i in range(0, len(string), every))
```

(For Python 2, use `xrange` instead of `range`.)

Comment: This solution is an order of magnitude faster. `timeit.timeit` says 100000 executions of the regexp solution take 27.8 seconds, while 100000 executions of your shorter solution take 4.45 seconds).

Comment: I'd also say that the shorter version is the "most pythonic" one: a one-liner, quite elegant, using generators and the `join` method.

Answer (score 21):

I'd go with:

```
import textwrap
s = "0123456789"*100
print('\n'.join(textwrap.wrap(s, 64)))
```

Comment: `textwrap` is space aware, so this won't handle `"12345 "*100` correctly.

Answer (score 12):

Taking [@J.F. Sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4279/jfs)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2657758/305689) one step further (this is *nearly* criminal! `:-)` ):

```
import textwrap
s = "0123456789"*100
print textwrap.fill(s, 64)
```

Look ma... no regexes! because as you know... http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247

Thanks for introducing us to [`textwrap`](http://docs.python.org/library/textwrap.html) module... although it's been in Python since 2.3, I wasn't aware of it until now (yes, i'll admit that publically)!!

Comment: `textwrap` is space aware, so this won't handle `"12345 "*100` correctly.

Answer (score 7):

Tiny, not nice:

```
"".join(s[i:i+64] + "\n" for i in xrange(0,len(s),64))
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest the following method:

```
"\n".join(re.findall("(?s).{,64}", s))[:-1]
```

This is, more-or-less, the non-RE method taking advantage of the RE engine for the loop.

On a very slow computer I have as a home server, this gives:

```
$ python -m timeit -s 's="0123456789"*100; import re' '"\n".join(re.findall("(?s).{,64}", s))[:-1]'
10000 loops, best of 3: 130 usec per loop
```

AndiDog's method:

```
$ python -m timeit -s "s='0123456789'*100; import re" 're.sub("(?s)(.{64})", r"\1\n", s)'
1000 loops, best of 3: 800 usec per loop
```

gurney alex's 2nd/Michael's method:

```
$ python -m timeit -s "s='0123456789'*100" '"\n".join(s[i:i+64] for i in xrange(0, len(s), 64))'
10000 loops, best of 3: 148 usec per loop
```

I don't consider the `textwrap` method to be correct for the specification of the question, so I won't time it.

#### EDIT

Changed answer because it was incorrect (shame on me!)

#### EDIT 2

Just for the fun of it, the RE-free method using `itertools`. It rates third in speed, and it's not Pythonic (too lispy):

```
"\n".join(
   it.imap(
     s.__getitem__,
     it.imap(
       slice,
       xrange(0, len(s), 64),
       xrange(64, len(s)+1, 64)
     )
   )
 )

$ python -m timeit -s 's="0123456789"*100; import itertools as it' '"\n".join(it.imap(s.__getitem__, it.imap(slice, xrange(0, len(s), 64), xrange(64, len(s)+1, 64))))'
10000 loops, best of 3: 182 usec per loop
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work correctly. If you put more than 64 characters in it outputs a newline after every character rather than after every 64 characters.

Comment: Spot on, biffabacon. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

[itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) has a nice recipe for a function `grouper` that is good for this, particularly if your final slice is less than 64 chars and you don't want a slice error:

```
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

Use like this:

```
big_string = <YOUR BIG STRING>
output = '\n'.join(''.join(chunk) for chunk in grouper(big_string, 64))
```