# Why are textwrap.wrap() and textwrap.fill() so slow?

Tags: python

Why are [`textwrap.wrap()`](http://docs.python.org/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.wrap) and [`textwrap.fill()`](http://docs.python.org/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.fill) so slow? For example, to wrap a string of 10000 characters on my laptop takes nearly two and a half seconds.

```
$ python -m timeit -n 10 -s 's = "A" * 10000; import textwrap' 'textwrap.fill(s)'
10 loops, best of 3: 2.41 sec per loop
```

Compare that to this code adapted from [an answer to a related Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2657733/38140)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# simplewrap.py
def fill(text, width=70):
    return '\n'.join(text[i:i+width] for i in
                     range(0, len(text), width))
```

which wraps the text orders of magnitude faster than `textwrap`:

```
$ python -m timeit -n 10 -s 's = "A" * 10000; import simplewrap' 'simplewrap.fill(s)'
10 loops, best of 3: 37.2 usec per loop
```

Comment: TextWrap wraps words, probably with a lot of non-latin scripts support, while your simple code blindly breaks string into 70-length arrays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`textwrap`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/textwrap.py) does a *lot* more than what your simple, streamlined example program does. It constructs a new class, compiles some regexes to handle all kinds of whitespace and other wrap-able character combinations etc.

It's not really a fair comparison, especially since (as hamstergene noted) your quoted program
does not actually wrap the text.

Answer (score 8):

Profiling the code reveals that the time is taken up by the regular expression intended to split the input into words. A stripped down version of it that exhibits the same issue is:

```
import re
s = "A" * 10000
wordsep_re = re.compile(
    r'\w+[^\W]-'
    )
wordsep_re.split(s)
```

I believe Python uses recursive backtracking to match regular expressions. I think whats going on is that python keeps trying to match the - and failing, thus having to back up.

You can use:

```
textwrap.fill(s, break_on_hyphens = False)
```

Which you'll find is really fast. The regular expression for matching hyphens has a pathological case when the text doesn't have any spaces in it.

Answer (score 2):

You're testing a particular pathological case. A single, nonbreakable string performs terribly:

```
~: python -m timeit -n 10 -s 's = "A"*10000; import textwrap' 'textwrap.fill(s)'
10 loops, best of 3: 1.62 sec per loop
```

But 1000 words of nine characters each, separated by spaces, runs 300 times faster:

```
~: python -m timeit -n 10 -s 's = "AAAAAAAAA " * 1000; import textwrap' 'textwrap.fill(s)'
10 loops, best of 3: 5.46 msec per loop
```