# Splitting long string without breaking words fulfilling lines

Tags: python, string, algorithm

*Before you think that it's duplicated (there are many question asking how to split long strings without breaking words) take in mind that my problem is a bit different: order is not important and I've to fit the words in order to use every line as much as possible.*

I've a unordered set of words and I want to combine them without using more than 253 characters.

```
def compose(words):
    result = " ".join(words)
    if len(result) > 253:
        pass # this should not happen!
    return result
```

My problem is that I want to try to fill the line as much as possible. For example:

```
words = "a bc def ghil mno pq r st uv"
limit = 5 # max 5 characters

# This is good because it's the shortest possible list,
#   but I don't know how could I get it
# Note: order is not important
good = ["a def", "bc pq", "ghil", "mno r", "st uv"]

# This is bad because len(bad) > len(good)
#   even if the limit of 5 characters is respected
# This is equivalent to:
#   bad  = ["a bc", "def", "ghil", "mno", "pq r", "st uv"]
import textwrap
bad = textwrap.wrap(words, limit)
```

How could I do?

Comment: This is a dynamic programming problem; attack it the same way you'd attack the [coin change problem](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-7-coin-change/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Non-optimal offline fast 1D bin packing Python algorithm**

```
def binPackingFast(words, limit, sep=" "):
    if max(map(len, words)) > limit:
        raise ValueError("limit is too small")
    words.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
    res, part, others = [], words[0], words[1:]
    for word in others:
        if len(sep)+len(word) > limit-len(part):
            res.append(part)
            part = word
        else:
            part += sep+word
    if part:
        res.append(part)
    return res
```

**Performance**

Tested over `/usr/share/dict/words` (provided by `words-3.0-20.fc18.noarch`) it can do half million words in a second on my slow dual core laptop, with an efficiency of at least 90% with those parameters:

```
limit = max(map(len, words))
sep = ""
```

With `limit *= 1.5` I get 92%, with `limit *= 2` I get 96% (same execution time).

Optimal (theoretical) value is calculated with: `math.ceil(len(sep.join(words))/limit)`

> no efficient bin-packing algorithm can be guaranteed to do better

Source: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Bin-PackingProblem.html

**Moral of the story**

While it's interesting to find the best solution, I think that for the most cases it would be much better to use this algorithm for 1D offline bin packing problems.

**Resources**

- http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Bin-PackingProblem.html
- https://github.com/hudora/pyShipping/

**Notes**

- I didn't use textwrap for my implementation because it's slower than my simple Python code.
  Maybe it's related with: [Why are textwrap.wrap() and textwrap.fill() so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781261/why-are-textwrap-wrap-and-textwrap-fill-so-slow)
- It seems to work perfectly even if the sorting is not reversed.

Answer (score 5):

This is the [bin packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem); the solution is NP-hard, although there exist non-optimal heuristic algorithms, principally first fit decreasing and best fit decreasing.  See https://github.com/type/Bin-Packing for implementations.

Comment: Thanks :) I found this: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Bin-PackingProblem.html - If I understand correctly the best non-optimal solution is the one proposed in this page (sort by length from the longest to the shortest and filling the buckets). I don't know if it could be valid for 2d and 3d problems too.