# Algo for splitting QString by given number, without breaking the words in Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, word-wrap, text-processing, qstring

I have Long String with meaningful sentences in it. I want split it by given number of chars a part will hold without breaking the last word of part.

I wrote an algo which is splitting string fine but the words in parts are getting mixed up and are being placed in random location.

My code:

```
QString str = "कोरोना वायरस के संक्रमण से स्पेन में शुक्रवार 932 लोगों की मौत हुई. इसके साथ ही स्पेन में मरने वालों की कुल 
               संख्या 10 हज़ार 935 पहुंच गई है. इटली के बाद स्पेन दुनिया का दूसरा देश है जहां कोरोना वायरस से सबसे ज़्यादा मौतें हुई हैं.";
int m = 30;
QStringList words = str.split(" ");
QStringList result;
 while(words.isEmpty()==false){
    QString strPart;
    if(QString(words.join(" ")).length()>m){
        for (int i = 0; i < words.count(); i++) {
            if(strPart.count()<m){
                strPart.append(words.at(i)+" ");
                words.removeAt(i);
            }
        }
    }else if(QString(words.join(" ")).length()<m){
        for (int i = 0; i < words.count(); i++) {
             strPart.append(words.join(" "));
             words.clear();
        }
    }
    result.append(strPart);
 }
qDebug() <<result;
```

and the result in debug is :

```
("कोरोना के से में 932 की हुई. साथ ", "वायरस स्पेन लोगों इसके स्पेन मरने ", "संक्रमण मौत में की संख्या हज़ार ", "शुक्रवार वालों 10 पहुंच है. के ", "ही 935 इटली स्पेन का देश जहां ", "कुल बाद दूसरा कोरोना से ज़्यादा ", "गई है सबसे हुई ", "दुनिया वायरस मौतें हैं.")
```

Any help will be appreciated.
I found a [python code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16426253/3792923) for doing same thing but am not able to port it to c++

Comment: Please, have a closer look at the first inner loop: `for (int i = 0; i < words.count(); i++) {` and the inside `words.removeAt(i);`. If you remove a word from `words`, all the following words shift one index down. So, in the next iteration, the direct succeeder is skipped. If you remove a word, you may fix the `i` respectively (e.g. by `--i;`) to compensate this. That's just what I saw on the second glance. (Unfortunately, the text of your sample looks to me just like a nice pattern on the wall paper. That makes it a bit hard to prove my suspicion by eyes.) :-)

Comment: Why do you remove words from `words` at all? If you initialize `int i = 0` before the outer loop and let the inner loops just iterate over it (without resetting it to 0 and removing words) you can iterate over the whole list building your `strPart` and `result` just without changing anything in `words`.

Comment: Thanks @Scheff , i put --i in first for loop and it fixed my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @scheff suggestion the solution proposed by him of adding `--i` to update value of `i` in first for loop works final code is given below for future.

```
QString str = "कोरोना वायरस के संक्रमण से स्पेन में शुक्रवार 932 लोगों की मौत हुई. इसके साथ ही स्पेन में मरने वालों की कुल 
               संख्या 10 हज़ार 935 पहुंच गई है. इटली के बाद स्पेन दुनिया का दूसरा देश है जहां कोरोना वायरस से सबसे ज़्यादा मौतें हुई हैं.";
int m = 30;
QStringList words = str.split(" ");
QStringList result;
 while(words.isEmpty()==false){
    QString strPart;
    if(QString(words.join(" ")).length()>m){
        for (int i = 0; i < words.count(); i++) {
            if(strPart.count()<m){
                strPart.append(words.at(i)+" ");
                words.removeAt(i);
                --i; // updated here
            }
        }
    }else if(QString(words.join(" ")).length()<m){
             strPart.append(words.join(" "));
             words.clear();
    }
    result.append(strPart);
 }
qDebug() <<result;
```