# wrap all lines that are longer than line length

Tags: python, python-3.x, computer-science

I am writing a program that limits each line to a certain length.

this is what i got so far, i am almost done but i still need to cut each line, but i cant figure it out.

```
def main():
    filename = input("Please enter the name of the file to be used: ")
    openFile = open(filename, 'r+')
    file = openFile.read()
    lLength = int(input("enter a number between 10 & 20: "))

    while (lLength < 10) or (lLength > 20) :
        print("Invalid input, please try again...")
        lLength = int(input("enter a number between 10 & 20: "))

    wr = textwrap.TextWrapper()
    wraped = wr.wrap(file)

    print("Here is your output formated to a max of", lLength, "characters per line: ")

    wr.width = lLength
    wr.expand_tabs = True
    for lines in wraped:
        print(lines)
```

Edit:

```
def main():
    filename = input("Please enter the name of the file to be used: ")
    openFile = open(filename, 'r')
    file = openFile.read()
    lLength = int(input("enter a number between 10 & 20: "))

    while (lLength < 10) or (lLength > 20) :
        print("Invalid input, please try again...")
        lLength = int(input("enter a number between 10 & 20: "))
    if (lLength > 10) or (lLength < 20):
        print("\nYour file contains the following text: \n" + file)
#=========================================================================
        wr = textwrap.TextWrapper(width=lLength)
        wraped = wr.wrap(file)

        print("\n\nHere is your output formated to a max of", lLength, "characters per line: ")

        for lines in wraped:
            print(lines)

main()
```

an example of what the output SHOULD be is this.
If the file specified contains this text:

```
hgytuinghdt #here the length is 11
ughtnjuiknshfyth #here the length is 16
nmjhkaiolgytuhngjuin #here the length is 20
```

and the lLength is specified to 15 then this should print out:

```
hgytuinghdt
ughtnjuiknshfyt
h
nmjhkaiolgytuhng
juin
```

Comment: Why are you opening the file in r+ mode if you're not planning to write to it?

Comment: Also, why specify `expand_tabs`? Are there tabs in your input files?

Comment: related: [Insert a newline character every 64 characters using Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2657693/4279)

Answer (score 3):

`wr = textwrap.TextWrapper()` should be `wr = textwrap.TextWrapper(width=length, expand_tabs=True)`
You should then remove `wr.width = lLength` and `wr.expand_tabs = True`. They should have been run before `wr.wrap()` was called, but since one can set it using keyword arguments in the `TextWrapper` constructor as shown at the very top, they can be removed.

*PS*: `for lines in wraped: print(lines)` can be replaced with `print(wraped)` if you use [`TextWrapper.fill`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.TextWrapper.fill).

Comment: when i do this the line limit is not right, when i limit to 15, for example it limits to something else.

Comment: @user1919840 That's because the wrap function returns a list of elements. Use `fill` instead (I've updated the answer).

Comment: @user1919840 wrap will not break a word. You can instead look for split().

Comment: fill seems to be doing something else, it shows one character per line

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal: Sure it will, unless you explicitly set [`break_long_words=False`](extwrap.html#textwrap.TextWrapper.break_long_words).

Comment: @user1919840 That's because `fill()` returns a string, and so the for loop iterates through each character of that string.

Comment: ive done these things and when i specify 15, for example again, it doesnt cut the lines after the 15th character.

Comment: @user1919840 That's because textwrap attempts to break the lines at word boundaries.

Comment: @RamchandraApte can this be changed?

Comment: @user1919840 Doesn't seem so. If you want a "dumb" text wrapper, then see Ankit Jaiswal's solution (but add brackets around `"\n".join(a)` to make it work in Python 3.x).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
line = 'nmjhkaiolgytuhngjuin'
n = 5 # set the width here
a = [line[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(line), n)]
print ("\n".join(a))
```

Comment: This (a) isn't valid Python 3.x, and (b) doesn't do the same thing the OP was trying to do. `textwrap` will try to wrap on spaces, and only break words if they're longer than `width`; your code will just break every `n` characters, without attempting to keep words together.

Comment: @abarnert I agree that OP has asked for text wrapping, however his comments on above answer suggest that he is looking for something like this.

Comment: this is almost what i want but still not quite, it doesnt wrap correctly after the first "wrap".....well is just not the wrap needed here

Answer (score 0):

**This might help you:**

```
def wrap(f,n):
        fi=open(f,"w+")
        rl=fi.readlines()    
        for i in range(0,len(rl)):
            if len(rl[i]) > n:
                fi.write(rl[i][:n] +"\n" + rl[i][n:])
                fi.Close()
            else:
                fi.write(rl[i])
                fi.close()
```