# python xml elementtree wrap text by number of characters

Tags: python, xml, tabs, whitespace, elementtree

I'm wondering in xml elementtree how to wrap the text?

For instance, I have the following text

```
4324OO234324O234O32O423423OO23O432O4OO23O4O32O423O423O4O234OO234234O234OO324O234
```

And I need to make sure that it wraps the text for every 10 characters e.g.
However, I also need to preserve the tabs/whitespace that is happening after each line.

```
<mydata>
        4324OO2343
        24O234O32O
        423423OO23
        O432O4OO2
        3O4O32O42
        3O423O4O2
        34OO234234
        O234OO324
        O234
</mydata>
```

Any idea of any easy way to do this in python 2.5.2?

This is not a replicate question, because this is xml elementtree specific... It might be possible to break the chars up into chunks, but then I have to use minidom.parseString and toprettyxml, to get the tabs - but I havent found a way to do it yet –

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert a newline character every 64 characters using Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657693/insert-a-newline-character-every-64-characters-using-python)

Comment: no its not, because this is xml elementtree specific... It might be possible to break the chars up into chunks, but then I have to use minidom.parseString and toprettyxml, to get the tabs - but I havent found a way to do it yet

Comment: still don't understand where `xml.elementtree` is involved in this question. Can you explain more?

Comment: In the first line, it states, in xml elementtree how to do this... I'm trying to break up a piece of text and preserve indentation...

Comment: Plain text like that can't be represented as elementtree, it requires a root element. Post minimal sample XML that you expected to produce that output XML

Comment: It has a root element <mydata> At the moment, the first line is given the correct indentation, but all lines afterwards have no indentation - theres definitely a way to do this in elementtree, but it's slightly eluding me at the moment... hence the question

Answer (score 0):

The poster that voted to close this question was not correct and didn't provide help towards a solution. The duplicate thread only provided part of the solution, which is not useful in this case.

In the end I resolved it the following way:

hexerre = re.sub("(.{80})", "\1\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t", hexer, 0)

By adding the tabs into the regex expression I was able to get the indentation needed.