# Replace every space after x chars with a "\n"

Tags: python, regex

The goals of the function is to split one single string into multiple lines to make it more readable. The goal is to replace the first space found after at least n characters (since the beginning of the string, or since the last "\n" dropped in the string)

**Hp**:

- you can assume no `\n` in the string

**Example**

```
Marcus plays soccer in the afternoon
```

f(10) should result in

```
Marcus plays\nsoccer in\nthe afternoon
```

The first space in `Marcus plays soccer in the afternoon`is skipped because `Marcus` is only 5 chars long. We put then a `\n` after `plays` and we start counting again. The space after soccer is therefore skipped, etc.

So far tried

```
def replace_space_w_newline_every_n_chars(n,s):
    return re.sub("(?=.{"+str(n)+",})(\s)", "\\1\n", s, 0, re.DOTALL)
```

inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657693/insert-a-newline-character-every-64-characters-using-python)

Comment: Just mention what problems do you have in your current code, and your question will be even better.

Comment: donno how you got \n after plays..

Comment: Split to words, count.

Comment: yes, *at least*. I somehow assumed it "implicit" but yes, @KarolyHorvath, you are  formally correct

Comment: Typical XY problem : see the textwrap module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing

```
(.{10}.*?)\s
```

with

```
$1\n
```

[Check it out here](https://regex101.com/r/zX5lZ0/1).

Example:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'Marcus plays soccer in the afternoo
>>> re.sub(r'(.{9}.*?)\s', r'\1\n', s)
'Marcus plays\nsoccer in\nthe afternoon'
```