# Split string xticks into multiple lines (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a matplotlib boxplot with very long strings as xticks. Is there a way to automatically split them into multiple lines to make the plot more clean? I am using the seaborn function `barplot` to create the graph.

This is the plot:[image]

And the code i use to create it:

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(15,13))
sns.barplot(x="Component",y="TTTR",color = "C0",data=new,dodge=False,edgecolor="black",zorder=3)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.grid(axis='y',zorder=0)
plt.title("10 most impactful components",size=30,y=1.04,**pfont)
plt.ylabel("Impact (Sum TTR in h)")
plt.xlabel('Component')
plt.tight_layout()
```

Comment: Try the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55375156/dividing-long-xticks-in-2-lines-matplotlib)

Comment: Is there also a solution that works with the seaborn function `barplot`?

Comment: I am not sure. This is some property of the axis so it can be done by accessing the axis object returned by the box plot

Comment: Seriously consider which part of a tick label like e.g. `L_C3_St17_pos B Ratchet and Piston Rod Guide_Cilindro Pneumático` is *actually relevant* to the person looking at the bar plot. It's likely _either_ the english _or_ the spanish part (separated by underscore characters), and you could remove the rest automatically e.g. with `.split('_')`.

Comment: @Asmus sadly there can be cases where everything is identical up to the last word

Comment: @Asmus it's portuguese by the way :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`seaborn.barplot` returns a `matplotlib.Axes` object so you could use `Axes.set_xticklabels` to update the labels afterwards, e.g.

```
import textwrap

max_width = 20
ax = sns.barplot(...)
ax.set_xticklabels(textwrap.fill(x.get_text(), max_width) for x in ax.get_xticklabels())
```

Comment: Cool, thanks! This way i don't have to write over my original dataframe!

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround: Replacing the label column in the pandas dataframe with the labels from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55375156/dividing-long-xticks-in-2-lines-matplotlib)

```py
new.Component = [re.sub("(.{20})", "\\1\n", label, 0, re.DOTALL) for label in new.Component]
sns.barplot(x="Component",y="TTTR",color ="C0",data=new,dodge=False,edgecolor="black",zorder=3)
```